# How can I change the textbutton color in the flutter showAboutDialog?

Tags: flutter

I'm using the `showAboutDialog` function from flutter to show used licences in my project. How ever I'm stuck with changing the text color of the `VIEW LICENSES` and `CLOSE` textbuttons. See this image for clarification:

[image: about dialog]

This is my code:

```
...
onTap: () {
  showAboutDialog(
    context: context,
    applicationName: 'bla',
    applicationLegalese: 'November 2023',
 );
},
```

What I tried so far is looking for a color field inside the `showAboutDialog` how ever I could not find anything. I'm assuming that I could change the color in my `MaterialApp` `ThemeData`. Unfortunately I was not able to find the specific theme to override the default styling of those textbuttons.

I tried the following in my `MaterialApp` `ThemeData` to change the color of `VIEW LICENSES` and `CLOSE` to green but that did not change anything:

```
textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(style: ButtonStyle(foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.green))
```

Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this one?

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ).copyWith(),      
    ),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: YourScreen(),
  );
}
```

[image: sample]

Comment: What if I already have a themeData but I want something different just for this instance/screen

Comment: @lordvidex  I'm not sure, but, I think "showAboutDialog" is not expect that situation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69811508/376967

Answer (score 92):

I was not satisfied with the answers here because all were showing only MaterialColor use-cases and I wanted a custom color. But I finally found something explaining it well on the following link.

https://blog.logrocket.com/new-material-buttons-in-flutter/

Basically, what is confusing is that the new design uses the primary color instead of the textStyle property. You can still apply the other answers to change the overall theme using a MaterialColor, and you can override the existing color theme using any color by using primary under TextButton.styleFrom.

Example for anywhere in the app:

```
TextButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        foregroundColor: Colors.pink,
      ),
      child: Text(
        'TextButton (New)',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
      ),
    )
```

Example for the theme:

```
textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        primary: kDarkColor, // This is a custom color variable
        textStyle: GoogleFonts.fredokaOne(),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: It would be easier to add an option of simple "color" key

Answer (score 16):

You can use this:

```
return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
          textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
              style: ButtonStyle(
                  foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                      (state) => Colors.orange)))),
      home: MyWidget(),
    );
```

`MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith` takes a function, you can specify the color based on states, such as

```
MaterialState.pressed,
MaterialState.hovered,
MaterialState.focused,
```

[More info on this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialStateProperty-class.html).

Answer (score 3):

i run this code.
after some research i find out this way to change colour.

for this you need to set application main theme colour change, like this

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.brown,//i am set brown colour,you can set your colour here 
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: YourScreen(),
    );
  }
```

after this its work,

```
showAboutDialog(
                  context: context,
                  applicationName: 'bla',
                  applicationLegalese: 'November 2023',
                );
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the colors only for the dialog and not for the whole app, you have to create a new context. Surround the Button that showing the dialog with a `Theme` and a `Builder`

```
Theme(
    data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
      colorScheme: colorScheme.copyWith(primary: Colors.green),
    ),
    child: Builder(
      builder: (context) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text('show dialog'),               
          onTap: () => showAboutDialog(
                          context: context,
                          ...) 
        );
      },
    ),
  )
```