# The named parameter 'color' isn't defined. flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

```dart
body: Center(
       child: TextButton(
         onPressed: _handleSignIn,
         child: Text('Google Sign in'),
         color: Colors.amber,
       ),
     ),
   );
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64785742/how-can-i-change-the-textbutton-color-in-the-flutter-showaboutdialog

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the textbutton color in the flutter showAboutDialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64785742/how-can-i-change-the-textbutton-color-in-the-flutter-showaboutdialog)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant have `color` directly like that.

You can use `style` property like

```dart
child: TextButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Text(
    'Google Sign in',
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
  ),
  style: ButtonStyle(
    textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(
      TextStyle(color: Colors.amber),
    ),
    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.amber),
  ),
),
```

Find more about [`ButtonStyle`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonStyle-class.html)

Comment: Glad to help, you can explore the link for more.

Comment: im facing another problems in flutter i need ur help.how can i contact you please?

Comment: You can create another question with minimal snippet, If i fails, others may also be able to help.